# Serializable issue on PrintDocument class

Tags: c#, serialization, printdocument

I am using a software called Laserfiche. This has a workflow server and an SDK that allows you to use your own custom activities.
There is a requirement when you create a custom activity. It must be serialize.
So I put the property [Serializable] on all the classes.
The issue is when I use the System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument class.
I get:

> 02/09/2013 13:07:12 v9SignoffAuthentication Type
>   'System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument' in Assembly 'System.Drawing,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not marked as serializable.

I google a bit and found that PrintDocument cannot be serialize.
I add the property

```
[NonSerialized]
PrintDocument pd;
```

And the custom activity run but not completely. I get an exception on

```
 pd.Print();
```

This is inside an override method

```
protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
```

The error is

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at WFPrintCustomActivity.WFPrintCustomActivity.Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)||02/09/2013 13:15:38

If I mark an object as NonSerialized, I can't call one of this methods later?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Gianfranco

Comment: It ought to be a bit obvious, by marking the field [NonSerialized] it will have its default value for a deserialized object.  Which is null.  You'll need to give it a value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hans Passant,
That was the answer.
I was initializing pd inside the

```
  Public WFPrintCustomActivity()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                settings = new Settings();
                //Logs("STARTED");


                pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
            }
```

I commented those 2 lines

```
    pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
```

And initialize pd inside

protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)

Which runs first.
Now is working.

This is the first time I ask something on stackoverflow and I wanted to mark your comment as an answer. I don